# Regex to Match All Whitespace After Word

Tags: regex

I have strings like this: 
`"2015/08/this filename has whitespace .jpg"`

I need to match the whitespace characters in those strings.  They will all have `"2015/08/` and will end with `"`.

I'm using Sublime Text 2 to search and replace in a SQL DB dump.  I'm at a loss on how to do the match.  I know I can match whitespace with `\s`, but I have no clue how to contain to those groups.

Comment: Please describe what is wrong with [`\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/gH2oI8/2): which spaces should not be matched? Or do you want to match spaces outside the quotes? Like `\s+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`?

Comment: You can use `"2015/08/.+.jpg"`

Comment: I'm trying to match all spaces inside the quotes that come after `"2015/08/` and end at first `.jpg`.

Comment: Like [`\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/gH2oI8/3)? Please let me know if it works for you. It is a bit more generic than what you request.

Comment: It works great a regex101, but not in Sublime Text.  That may be for me to work out myself.

Comment: Actually, it was my error.  This works.  Your answer below matches the words as well.  I'll accept this if you want to update.

Comment: Well, they both should work but since the one above worked well, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, this expression should work **for a string that has the same number of opening/closing double quotes**:

```
\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/gH2oI8/3). The look-ahead is checking for an odd number of double quotes until the end of file.

[image]

Another approach is to define the boundary with `\G` and trim the beginning of the match with `\K`:

```
(?:"\d{4}\/\d{2}\/|(?!^)\G)[^"\s]*\K\s(?=[^"]*")
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH2oI8/4)

[image]

The regex finds a match:

- `(?:"\d{4}\/\d{2}\/|(?!^)\G)` - when a substring starts with numbers like `2015/12/` or after a successful match
- `[^"\s]*\K` - matches all characters that are not whitespace or `"` and omits them due to `\K` operator
- `\s` - here it matches a whitespace symbol
- `(?=[^"]*")` - a look-ahead checking we are presumably inside double quotes.

Replacing the spaces with, say, `%20` results in:

[image]

Comment: Note I think both solutions are valid assuming the number of opening and closing quotes is equal.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.